# What is returned by a search with Tire gem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, tire

What is returned when I do a search with the Tire gem in Rails (using Active Record integration)? Is the actual models returned or is it some generic object? I don't understand what I get back.

Answer (score 1):

It is an object of collection class. you can check this link
https://github.com/karmi/tire/blob/master/lib/tire/results/collection.rb

Answer (score -1):

Please read the Tire's README carefully, namely the parts about the `:load` option for model search methods.

For background, search Github issues for `Item`, and see unit/integration tests for `Tire::Results::Collection` and `Tire::Results::Item`.